# Aligning the objects in SVG center

Tags: html, css, svg

How can i align objects within svg tag center. I can make it aligned by adjusting the x,y cordiantes in viewbox. But every time i need to change the value according to the size of object. How can i achieve centering the object within SVG respective of any size of object. To be more clear i want the icon to be centered horizontally and vertically within the red border. Refer my code below

```css
svg{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg height="20" width="20" viewBox="0 0 35 35">
 <path fill="#6d6d6d" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M19.0625,8.75 C18.81,8.75 18.585,8.6475 18.415,8.4875 C18.41,8.4825 18.4025,8.4825 18.3975,8.4775 L16.0675,6.145 L10.1675,12.045 C9.5575,12.6525 8.5675,12.6525 7.9575,12.045 C7.3475,11.435 7.3475,10.445 7.9575,9.835 L13.855,3.9375 L11.5225,1.6025 C11.5175,1.5975 11.5175,1.59 11.5125,1.585 C11.3525,1.415 11.25,1.19 11.25,0.9375 C11.25,0.42 11.67,0 12.1875,0 L18.75,0 C19.44,0 20,0.56 20,1.25 L20,7.8125 C20,8.33 19.58,8.75 19.0625,8.75 Z M2.5,5.625 L2.5,16.875 C2.5,17.22 2.78,17.5 3.125,17.5 L14.375,17.5 C14.72,17.5 15,17.22 15,16.875 L15,10 L17.5,12.5 L17.5,17.5 C17.5,18.8825 16.3825,20 15,20 L2.5,20 C1.12,20 0,18.8825 0,17.5 L0,5 C0,3.62 1.12,2.5 2.5,2.5 L7.5,2.5 L10,5 L3.125,5 C2.78,5 2.5,5.28 2.5,5.625 Z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: How did you come up with the viewbox of `35` pixels in length? Do you always have a `path` of varying size within a 35 pixel viewbox?

Comment: I'm reusing this icon at different places. i will change 35 to 25 in viewbox. At this time i need to change x,y co-ordinates manually to center it. So i'm looking for dynamic solution to center it

Comment: So why do you specify a viewbox that does not match the `path` which is in it? Do you use that for scaling? You could scale the SVG using `width` and `height` then, and then center the `svg` within its parent element.

Comment: Can you share some tried out code

Comment: I had something along the lines of @mlunoe's answer in mind

Comment: Keep viewBox="0 0 20 20", and vary the height and width.  wrap the item in a div and try these: .svg--center {    background: blue;  display: inline-block;  width: 100px;  line-height: 100px;  text-align: center;  vertical-align: middle;}  line-height is necessary for vertical-align to work.  and width is needed for centering.

Answer (score 4):

you can use getBBox() to get the size of your path, and then adjust your viewBox accordingly...

```js
var box=path.getBBox()
svg.setAttribute("viewBox",`${box.x} ${box.y} ${box.width} ${box.height}`)

console.log(box)
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid red}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" height="20" width="20" viewBox="0 0 35 35">
 <path id="path" fill="#6d6d6d" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M19.0625,8.75 C18.81,8.75 18.585,8.6475 18.415,8.4875 C18.41,8.4825 18.4025,8.4825 18.3975,8.4775 L16.0675,6.145 L10.1675,12.045 C9.5575,12.6525 8.5675,12.6525 7.9575,12.045 C7.3475,11.435 7.3475,10.445 7.9575,9.835 L13.855,3.9375 L11.5225,1.6025 C11.5175,1.5975 11.5175,1.59 11.5125,1.585 C11.3525,1.415 11.25,1.19 11.25,0.9375 C11.25,0.42 11.67,0 12.1875,0 L18.75,0 C19.44,0 20,0.56 20,1.25 L20,7.8125 C20,8.33 19.58,8.75 19.0625,8.75 Z M2.5,5.625 L2.5,16.875 C2.5,17.22 2.78,17.5 3.125,17.5 L14.375,17.5 C14.72,17.5 15,17.22 15,16.875 L15,10 L17.5,12.5 L17.5,17.5 C17.5,18.8825 16.3825,20 15,20 L2.5,20 C1.12,20 0,18.8825 0,17.5 L0,5 C0,3.62 1.12,2.5 2.5,2.5 L7.5,2.5 L10,5 L3.125,5 C2.78,5 2.5,5.28 2.5,5.625 Z"/>
</svg>
```

P.S.: just do this once and change your viewBox manually in your code...

Answer (score 1):

You can move the `min-x` and `min-y` coordinates to place your content in the center. Description of the `viewBox` can be found here:
https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/

The better way to go about it is to export the file with the correct bounding box to get it completely center aligned. Opened your svg (in Sketch) added an invisible box around it of 35 x 35px, it exported to whole thing and cleaned it up:

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 35 35">
  <path fill="#6d6d6d" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M26.15625,16.875 C25.929,16.875 25.7265,16.78275 25.5735,16.63875 C25.569,16.63425 25.56225,16.63425 25.55775,16.62975 L23.46075,14.5305 L18.15075,19.8405 C17.60175,20.38725 16.71075,20.38725 16.16175,19.8405 C15.61275,19.2915 15.61275,18.4005 16.16175,17.8515 L21.4695,12.54375 L19.37025,10.44225 C19.36575,10.43775 19.36575,10.431 19.36125,10.4265 C19.21725,10.2735 19.125,10.071 19.125,9.84375 C19.125,9.378 19.503,9 19.96875,9 L25.875,9 C26.496,9 27,9.504 27,10.125 L27,16.03125 C27,16.497 26.622,16.875 26.15625,16.875 Z M11.25,14.0625 L11.25,24.1875 C11.25,24.498 11.502,24.75 11.8125,24.75 L21.9375,24.75 C22.248,24.75 22.5,24.498 22.5,24.1875 L22.5,18 L24.75,20.25 L24.75,24.75 C24.75,25.99425 23.74425,27 22.5,27 L11.25,27 C10.008,27 9,25.99425 9,24.75 L9,13.5 C9,12.258 10.008,11.25 11.25,11.25 L15.75,11.25 L18,13.5 L11.8125,13.5 C11.502,13.5 11.25,13.752 11.25,14.0625 Z" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.svg--center{  
  background: pink;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg--center">
  <svg height="20" width="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
 <path fill="#6d6d6d" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M19.0625,8.75 C18.81,8.75 18.585,8.6475 18.415,8.4875 C18.41,8.4825 18.4025,8.4825 18.3975,8.4775 L16.0675,6.145 L10.1675,12.045 C9.5575,12.6525 8.5675,12.6525 7.9575,12.045 C7.3475,11.435 7.3475,10.445 7.9575,9.835 L13.855,3.9375 L11.5225,1.6025 C11.5175,1.5975 11.5175,1.59 11.5125,1.585 C11.3525,1.415 11.25,1.19 11.25,0.9375 C11.25,0.42 11.67,0 12.1875,0 L18.75,0 C19.44,0 20,0.56 20,1.25 L20,7.8125 C20,8.33 19.58,8.75 19.0625,8.75 Z M2.5,5.625 L2.5,16.875 C2.5,17.22 2.78,17.5 3.125,17.5 L14.375,17.5 C14.72,17.5 15,17.22 15,16.875 L15,10 L17.5,12.5 L17.5,17.5 C17.5,18.8825 16.3825,20 15,20 L2.5,20 C1.12,20 0,18.8825 0,17.5 L0,5 C0,3.62 1.12,2.5 2.5,2.5 L7.5,2.5 L10,5 L3.125,5 C2.78,5 2.5,5.28 2.5,5.625 Z"/>
    </svg></div>
```